# RecyclerView onClickListener and ViewType

Tags: android

I have a RecyclerView which I want to attach an onClickListener too, however I get a null object error when clicking on the items. It would seem my onclicklistener isn't being attached correctly?

There is also another problem, the correct viewholder doesn't seem to be returned?

EDIT: Seems to be some sort of issue with the viewHolder and view variables, but not sure what....

```
        @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {

        // Variable to hold the view and view holder.
        View view = null;
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

        // Choose which field type to display.
        switch (viewType) {
            case TEMPLATE_DETAILS_FIELD:
                view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.templates_add_template_details_field, viewGroup, false);
                viewHolder = new TemplateDetailsField(view);
            case SECTION_FIELD:
                view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.templates_add_section_field, viewGroup, false);
                viewHolder = new SectionField(view);
            case HEADING_FIELD:
                // Create the new view.
                view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.templates_add_heading_field, viewGroup, false);

                // Create a new heading field.
                HeadingField headingField = new HeadingField(view);

                // Attach the edittext listener to it.
                headingField.getHeading().addTextChangedListener(new TitleTextWatcher(headingField.getTitle(), headingField.getHeading()));
                viewHolder = headingField;
            default:
                // Do nothing here.
                break;
        }

        //Create a temp view holder for the onclick listener.
        final RecyclerView.ViewHolder tempViewHolder = viewHolder;

        // Set the onclick listener to expand and contract the view.
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FrameLayout expandedView = (FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.expanded_view);
                // Check if the child view is visible or not.
                if (expandedView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {

                    // View is visible, hide the view.
                    expandedView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    // Add to expanded state array list.
                    mRecyclerViewExpandedState.set(tempViewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), false);
                } else {

                    // View is not visible, show the view.
                    expandedView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    // Add to expanded state array list.
                    mRecyclerViewExpandedState.set(tempViewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), true);
                }
            }
        });

        return viewHolder;
    }
```

Comment: You can try like: viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener();
And you don't need to user tempViewHolder.

Comment: I'm getting the following error. viewHolder may product a null pointer exception on the line             viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

Comment: It will be warning if I am not wrong. Try initialising viewHolder in default: case as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use this as a click listener,

```
import android.content.Context;  
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;  
import android.view.GestureDetector;  
import android.view.MotionEvent;  
import android.view.View;

public class RecyclerItemClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {  
private OnItemClickListener mListener;

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}

GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, OnItemClickListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
    View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
    if (childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
        mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
  }
}
```

Using it in code is very simple. Just add an item touch listener of this class to the `RecyclerView`:

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(  
  new RecyclerItemClickListener(context, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
    // TODO Handle item click
  }
})
);
```